# How can I join consecutive SVN and BZR repos into GIT?

Tags: git, svn, bazaar

A strange request, I admit...

We have a project that is currently managed in Bazaar, but was previously stored in Subversion. However, rather that copying the history across, the previous developers took a single export of the SVN repo and started a brand-new BZR repo.

Thus, we have the following:

```
SVN: A-B-C-D
BZR: E-F-G-H
```

And what I want is:

```
GIT: A-B-C-D-E-D-G-H
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest with `git filter-branch`. In fact, this is one of the examples in the filter-branch documentation:

> To set a commit (which typically is at the tip of another history) to be the parent of the current initial commit, in order to paste the other history behind the current history:

```
       git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <graft-id>/"' HEAD
```

So here `<graft-id>` is your commit D, assuming you are working from a branch consisting of the BZR commits E to H. So I assume you've used migration tools to get both the svn and bzr histories into git, and imported them as separate branches into a single repository.

Comment: I used a slightly different process (using .git/info/grafts followed by the filter-tree), but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!